# Why isn't my computer starting up at a specific time?

Tags: bios, power-management

I'm using the BIOS' function of waking it by alarm, yet it doesn't actually do anything.

Any ideas why this might not be working?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Window's Power Options, toggle the Quick Start option. This setting seems to mess with the automatic boot state set by the BIOS.

[Source](http://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?topic=16783.0)

Comment: Oh wow, that was probably also what was messing with my AHK scripts. Will see if it powers up tomorrow as it should, if so, marking this as an answer.